# The fastest way to check whether remote computer is offline

Tags: c#, network-programming, remote-access

I need a fastest way to check whether remote computer is **off**. There are some ways I've tried, but none of them gives me desired time speed (it should be less than 0.5 sec and it's critical, because occurs on context menu popup)

```
            //using System.Net
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
            //if error occurs - remote computer is off

            //using System.Net.NetworkInformation
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(hostIp);
            if (pingReply.Status != IPStatus.Success)
            {
                //Remote computer is off
            }

            //using System.Management
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + hostName + @"\root\cimv2", null);
            scope.Connect();
            //if error occurs - remote computer is off
```

As far as I can see the fastest way is by using Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName) - but still it takes it about 3 sec to throw an exception. 
Any idea?

Comment: Is the list of computers you want to check limited?

Comment: Yes, every time it's only one specific computer.

Comment: What you're asking for is impossible unless you can guarantee that the remote computer responds within 0.5 seconds when online, and you can't guarantee that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Ping with timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcc2xffs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This version of Send method will allow you to specify how long to wait for a response. If you define 500ms and the server you are checking is not on the other side of the planet or on the very high latency Internet connection, you can quite reliably say that either the target machine is down or that you have problems with your Internet connection.

Dns.GetHostEntry does not check whether the host is up or down. This works with DNS and only tries to resolve host name. DNS can be slow and can timeout even if the host name exists and just the used DNS server is not responsive.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be a way. The problem is  that ping may be prohibited on some networks.

Comment: If ping is not allowed, you can use other methods with timeouts - like TCP open port check or even HTTP request. But ICMP is lightweight and thus fastest. The fact that it was slow in your case is that the default timeout in the other versions of the method is much higher than 500ms. Also avoid using Send methods with hostname arguments. Always use the one with IPAddress to specify the target machine.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that it is just for one computer, why don't you have the logic on your answer running on a separate thread and caching the state of the computer? Your context popup would be reading from this cache and reacting "instantaneously", but the exact state could be a few seconds delayed... Now, depending on what you are doing with the computer afterwards (you did not mention in the answer), this might be an approach to consider...

Comment: When I say "one computer" I mean "one from list", i.e. there may be more. But separate thread in conjunction with other methods, like ping may be not bad solution.

Comment: Yep, what I meant was a fixed list of computers and not "any computer"... this way you can have a separate thread checking their states every X seconds and your popup is lightning fast.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're depending on so many factors (Network loads, Packet losses etc`), and additionally, when a computer is not responding immediately when he gets the request doesn't necessarily says it's online, you can't assume the computer is offline.
I don't think you can do it any faster than a ping request.

Comment: In my tests ping was the slowest one. And I cannot be sure pinging is allowed - it depends by network security settings.

Comment: The only true way of knowing of computer `X` is online and not just a computer that using an out-dated ip address of `X` is to create a Service in some sort, that will responsive to the client request of checking his life time.